# $N$ is an at most three digit number whose sum of digits equal to the product of its digits. How many possible values of $N$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The smallest number will be $123$.

The largest number will be $321$.

But how to proceed further, any clue please?

Comment: It looks like $22$ would also be a valid number... 2 digits satisfies the "at most 3 digits" restriction

Comment: @HarshKumar if my answer is wrong, by all means, downvote it and write a better one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For three digits, you rightly determined that $1+2+3 = 6 = 1\cdot2\cdot3$ is the only possible option. You have 6 numbers that you can construct from these digits: 123, 132, 213, 231, 312 and 321.

For two digits, $2+2 = 4 = 2\cdot2$. This yields only one number, 22.

For one digit, *all* 10 digits yield one solution, so ten in total.

So $N$ has 17 possible values.

Comment: @HarshKumar which one(s) did I miss? I suppose this question was asked having integer solutions in the decimal system in mind.

Comment: @HarshKumar the question says *at most three* digits.

Comment: Nice answer @Glorfindel. +1

Comment: The number system doesn't mater much.  a + b +c  and abc will have the same value  (but not notation) in any number system large enough to hold them.

Comment: @fleablood for two and three digits, it doesn't matter (except to exclude solutions in systems where 2 and 3 don't exist, i.e. the binary system). For one digit, it does.

Comment: Either, I misunderstand you or you misunderstand me and probably both.  For one digit $\sum a=\prod a=a $ is true of all digits regardless of base.  Or are you claiming the number of single digits is equal to the base and so in base b>=3 there will be b +7 solutions and that number will vary with b?  But we are on a tangent, I guess.  I don't think there are any other a+b+c=abc for any integers where values 10 or higher are acceptable.   At least I don't think there are.  Be fun to extend to four five or more digits.  (1+1+2+4=1x1x2x4)